# D3 - transition after reading updated data from external file

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I am trying to create a bar chart that has 'attendees' and 'coins'. The data is being read from an external file and I'd like to update the chart as the data changes (or check the file every couple seconds and update the data). I have been trying to follow along [mbostock's](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) tutorial on the general update pattern but have had a heck of a time even starting to adapt for my own chart. I didn't find any other questions/answers that dealt with transitioning data from external files, but if I missed something, please let me know. So, with that, I turn you all!

Here is my current JS code:

```
var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 950 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatNumber = d3.format(".1f");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.tickFormat(formatNumber);

var tip = d3.tip()
.attr('class', 'd3-tip')
.offset([-10, 0])
.html(function(d) {

return "<strong>Coins:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.coins + "</span>";
})

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.attendee; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.coins; })]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".5em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Coins");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.attendee); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.coins); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.coins); })
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
 });

function type(d) {
  d.coins = +d.coins;
  return d;
}

var inter = setInterval(function() {
update();
}, 1000);

function update() {

}
```

I should also mention that this is the first time really trying to dig deeper with D3. I hope I am not missing something too obvious! Thank you in advance for any help, suggestions, or pushes in the right direction!

** Edit to note the bar chart is an attempt to add functionality upon the sample found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579).

Edit 2: Adding .tsv here for better formatting:

```
 attendee   coins 
 George 35 
 Charlie    50 
 Harrison   50 
 Billy  45 
 Wally  30 
 Harley 40 
 Steven 120 
 Paul   30
```

Comment: hey, can you share a little bit of that tsv so we can test it out?

Comment: @torresomar Added in the main question for better formatting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can call the update function like this:

```
var inter = setInterval(updateChart, 5000);
```

The logic which would simulate the fetch is the following:

```
function fetchData() {
  console.log('fetching');
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var data = [{ 
      attendee: "Paul",
      coins: Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 1
    }, {
      attendee: "Bessy the Cow",
      coins: Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 1
    }, {
      attendee: "Zeke",
      coins: Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 1
    }];
    setTimeout(function() { // Adding timeout to simulate latency
      resolve(data);
    }, 4000)
  })
}
```

Then we create an update function which will use the newly retrieved data:

```
function updateChart() {
  fetchData()
    .then(function(data) {
      // Update our y domain with new coin values
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.coins;
      })]);
      // Update our axis because our y domain just changed
      svg.select('g.y')
        .transition()
        .duration(300)
        .ease("linear")
        .call(yAxis);
      // Create a new data join with the simuldated data
      var bars = svg.selectAll('.bar').data(data);
      // Remove extra elements (say new data just has 2 bars, this would remove third one)
      bars.exit().remove();
      // Update existing elements
      bars.transition()
        .duration(300)
        .ease("linear")
        .call(renderBar);
      // Add new elements (say new data has 5 bars, this would add the additional 2)
      bars.enter().append('rect')
        .transition()
        .duration(300)
        .ease("linear")
        .call(renderBar);
    })
}
```

I created the renderBar function since we are basically repeating the same routine at adding and updating.

```
function renderBar(rect) {
  rect.attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.attendee);
    })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.coins);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.coins);
    });
}
```

This plunkr shows the working code, I removed the d3.tip part:

http://plnkr.co/edit/X3vZp5sReOWBsuZrxf8D?p=preview

Comment: First off, thank you so much for the timely and thorough response. One question: My tips are updating properly without adding anything else to your updateChart()/renderBar() functions. Is that to be expected?

Comment: First of all, you have nothing to thank for. Second, yeah the tips will update properly since we are only updating the current three bars (in the plnkr) the events are still referenced by the bars thus having the latest information. Try adding an extra bar in the new data and you will see that you will need to create the events for that additional bar.